# Tagging schema for CouchDB. Would this work?

Tags: couchdb, tagging

I am wondering if the following scenario would be amenable to CouchDB?  I am building a web-based flashcard application. Users can create flashcards (question on one side, answer on the other). Flashcard authors and other users can tag flashcards with keywords/phrases. Users can retrieve/generate virtual stacks of cards based on tags including support for boolean search (tagA AND tagB NOT tagC OR tagD). The DB will store cards (obviously) but also “documents” for users, tags and potentially virtual stacks of cards. I have read other SO questions concerning tagging within CouchDB but am wondering if the following would work or be to write intensive … (1) Card documents contain JSON array of tag strings assigned to that card, (2) Tag documents contain JSON array of cards using the tag, (3) tag documents also have element to store count of cards using that tag, (4) whenever a new card is created or tag is added to a card, the associated card identifier is also added to the tag document and the tag document's CardCount element is incremented. (5) Permanent views of cards indexed by card ID and of tags indexed by tag string are generated. If I know the card ID I can find the document quickly and can quickly get a list of associated tags. If I am given a tag string I can quickly find the tag document and then get a list of card IDs using the tag. For more elaborate boolean search I can retrieve a list of card IDs for each tag in the boolean search and then figure out the union/intersection/etc of these sets on the client. Does this seem reasonable?  I am aware of the fulltext indexing option using Lucene but would like to avoid this if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a good reason to make things that complicated - just create a document per card and add tags to these documents as you go along. Create a few stored views to count/show tags and their usage number when you need it.

this way you'll only need:

card document:

question
answer
tags[]

views:

show card info
show (perhaps most popular) tags
show cards per tag

As long as your documents are properly structured, you won't need full text search to handle everything.